# HTTP request concurrency and reverse proxy

Tags: python, networking, proxy, multiprocessing, couchdb

Apologies if the title is not descriptive and I struggle to find a good title for the question.

My question involves Python, CouchDB (to a lesser degree), multiprocessing and networking. It started out as I was trying to debug a co-worker's program using Python's `multiprocessing` module to parallelize requests to a CouchDB database using [couchdb-python](https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python/). I created a minimal program to exhibit the bug and eventually solved the issue, but the solution drew another question which I was not able to answer to my best knowledge. I'm hoping experts on SO could help me with this, so here it goes.

The premise of the problem is pretty simple. We have `n` resources, all of which can be retrieved concurrently. Instead of making `n` serial requests, my co-worker is using the `multiprocessing` module to fetch all `n` resources in parallel. Here's a program I wrote to demonstrate the issue:

### The Script (bug.py)

```
import couchdb
import multiprocessing

server = couchdb.Server(SERVER)

try:
    database = server.create('test')
except:
    server.delete('test')
    database = server.create('test')

database.save({'_id': '1', 'type': 'dog', 'name': 'chase'})
database.save({'_id': '2', 'type': 'dog', 'name': 'rubble'})
database.save({'_id': '3', 'type': 'cat', 'name': 'kali'})

def query_id(id):
    print(dict(database[id]))

def main():
    args = [
        ['dog', 'chase'],
        ['dog', 'rubble'],
        ['cat', 'kali'],
    ]
    print('-' * 80)
    processes = []
    for id_ in ['1', '2', '3']:
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=query_id, args=(id_))
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pretty innocent code, right? Well, running it on the latest couchdb and couchdb-python gives the following error:

### The output

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Process Process-2:
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "bug.py", line 25, in query_id
  File "bug.py", line 25, in query_id
    print(dict(database[id]))
  File "/home/kevin/src/couchdb-python/couchdb/client.py", line 418, in __getitem__
    print(dict(database[id]))
  File "/home/kevin/src/couchdb-python/couchdb/client.py", line 418, in __getitem__
    return Document(data)
TypeError: 'ResponseBody' object is not iterable
    return Document(data)
TypeError: 'ResponseBody' object is not iterable
```

After some digging, I finally found out that couchdb-python's implementation of `ConnectionPool` is not multiprocess safe. See this [PR](https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python/pull/314) for more details. Basically, all processes share the same `ConnectionPool` object, and was given the same `httplib.HTTPConnection` object, and when they all simultaneously try to read from the connection, the string being returned is garbled, and the bug ensued. You can see the evidence of it if you put `print(os.getpid(), line)` inside `httplib.HTTPResponse._read_status` method. Here's a sample output after the print statement is added:

```
(26490, 'TP1.120 O\r\n')
(26489, 'T/ 0KServer: CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/17)\r\n')
Process Process-2:
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "bug.py", line 25, in query_id
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    print(dict(database[id]))
  File "/home/kevin/src/couchdb-python/couchdb/client.py", line 418, in __getitem__
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "bug.py", line 25, in query_id
    print(dict(database[id]))
  File "/home/kevin/src/couchdb-python/couchdb/client.py", line 418, in __getitem__
    return Document(data)
TypeError: 'ResponseBody' object is not iterable
    return Document(data)
TypeError: 'ResponseBody' object is not iterable
```

As seen here, the first line being read from the sub-processes are only partial, indicating a race condition here. If I further inspect the `HTTPConnection` object, I can see all three processes are sharing the same connection object, the socket to the server and the file descriptor from the socket that's being used for reading.

### Puzzle

So far so good. I've identified the root cause of the problem and put together a fix. However, complication arises when I put the couchdb instance behind a reverse proxy. In this case, I'm using haproxy. Here's a sample config:

```
global
    ...
defaults
    ...
listen couchdb
    bind *:9999
    mode http
    stats enable
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server couchdb-1 127.0.0.1:5984 check
```

and point the couchdb server url to `http://localhost:9999` in the bug script, reran the script, and everything was fine! I also inspected the connection object, the socket and the file descriptor, and there were also shared among all processes.

This got me puzzled. I brought up [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) and inspected what's going on in the two cases: with or without haproxy.

#### Without haproxy

When the parallel requests are made without haproxy, I observed in the mitmproxy details tab (I showed a single request, but the timing sequence is the same for all 3 concurrent requests):

[image: Without haproxy]

The event sequence here suggests a blocking synchronous request.

#### With haproxy[image: With haproxy]

You can see the sequence here is different from that without haproxy. Request is considered complete without the server connection being initiated.

### Question

I'm not used to working at this low level so I know my knowledge in this regard is pretty lacking here. I want to understand what difference did putting haproxy in front of it brought that subverted the multiprocessing bug in couchdb-python? haproxy is event-based, so I suspect that has something to do with it, but would really appreciate someone explaining the difference!

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: What happens when you remove `option httpclose` from your HAProxy configuration?

Comment: Just tried. In that case, the event sequence is exactly like that when it's not proxied (which makes the bug appear). So I guess `httpclose` is the difference here. Going off reading haproxy docs...

Comment: That's what I thought. `Connection: close` tells the client to close the connection after every request, which probably prevents pipelining and "fixes" your issue. The usual solution is to just open a new database connection inside each process, not share one globally.

Comment: Yes, I did identify that the problem is the share connection in couchdb-python. The part I didn't quite understand is even with `option httpclose`, the processes still share the same connection object (and hence the socket and file descriptor) but the issue doesn't appear.